# Ajax is not giving output

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make a like system. Everything works well without Ajax but with ajax is not ready.
I mean, The ajax post is ok, the answer is ok, but the output on the screen is not ok. When i click the LIKE button, noting happens (no page refresh). When i refresh the post, there is one more like. `
without ajax, the functions and everything is working

Here is my Ajax file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once ('../classes/comments.class.php');
$key = $_POST['key'];
$sessie = $_POST['login'];
    $like1 = new Comments();
    $like1 -> Key = $key;
    $like1 -> User = $sessie;
try{
    $feedback["status"] = "succes";
    $like1 -> addlikes();
    $feedback["message"] = $like1 -> CountLikes();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $feedback["message"] = $e -> getMessage();
    $feedback["status"] = "error";
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($feedback);
?>
```

and here the code in my PHP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#knop").click(function() {
                var login = $("#login").text();
                var key = $("#key").text();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "assets/ajax/check_likes.php",
                    data: { login : login , key : key},
                    success: function( msg ){
                        if ( msg.status == "success" ) {
                            $("#likes h1").text( msg.message );
                        }
                    }    
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Check the possible typo in your `try`: `$feedback["status"] = "succes"`. You have the following comparison on you php page: `if ( msg.status == "success" )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding an `exit();` after `echo json_encode($feedback);` in ajax file?

**Edit:** Also try using the console in Firebug (or chrome inspector or whatever) to check out if the ajax response is valid json.